# Mongo Aggregation mapping and query to fetch selective records for particular year using Mongo Template

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm using mongo template for querying documents based on state and zipcode which was achieved using Criteria and Query approach as below:

```
List<ModelClass> modelClass = null;
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
if(request.getState()!=null) {
  criteria = criteria.and("state").is(request.getState());
}
if(request.getZipcode()!=null) {
 criteria = criteria.and("zipcode").is(request.getZipcode());
}
Query query = new Query(criteria);

modelClass = mongoTemplate.find(query, ModelClass.class, "collectionName");
```

Below is my collection structure:

```
{
  "id": "5c59508688c12c9a3dc2dfe2",
  "zipcode": "12345",
  "state": "NY",
  "date": "2019-02-05T08:59:50.703",
  "status": "pass"
},
{
   "id": "5c5957216f4b9613c0c0b1ed",
    "zipcode": "45678",
    "state": "CO",
    "date": "2018-01-05T08:59:50.703",
    "status": "fail"
},
etc....
```

For passed year alone(eg.2019),Now I need to retrieve respective records extracting month part from date and using status field in my collection in order to process the passed and failed records for the UI. Got many examples using mongoShell direct query, But need help with the syntax using mongo template and necessary pojo class mapping to achieve the same. Also is it possible to achieve processing of passed and failed records for each month using mongo aggregation query itself?

Expecting some help/inputs from mongo experts on the right way to do it in single  fetch operation for both pass and fail scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have been able to achieve above requirement using mongo implementation itself. There might be better solutions available using latest mongo versions. I use spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE, so this might help anyone else looking for similar solution.

**Create class to support aggregation operation:**

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationContext;

import com.mongodb.DBObject;

public class CustomProjectAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {

    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomProjectAggregationOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria = criteria.and("date").gte(fromDate).lte(endDate).exists(true);

DBObject operation = (DBObject)new BasicDBObject("$group",
                          new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("month", 
                            new BasicDBObject("$month", "$date")))
                            .append("passCount", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 
                               new BasicDBObject("$cond", new Object[]{
                                 new BasicDBObject("$eq", new Object[]{ "$status", 
                                                               "Pass"}),1,0}))
                            ).append("failCount", new BasicDBObject(    
                                "$sum", new BasicDBObject("$cond", new Object[]{ 
                                   new BasicDBObject("$eq", new Object[]{ "$status", 
                                                            "Fail"}),1,0}))
                            ));

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(criteria),new 
                          CustomProjectAggregationOperation(operation));

List<ModelClass> modelList= mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,"collectionName",ModelClass.class).getMappedResults();
```

**Model Class Reference for any mongo newbies like me:**

```
public class ModelClass{

    private String month;
    private int passCount;
    private int failCount;

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month= month;
    }
    public int getPassCount() {
        return passCount;
    }
    public void setPassCount(int passCount) {
        this.passCount= passCount;
    }
    public int getFailCount() {
        return failCount;
    }
    public void setFailCount(int failCount) {
        this.failCount = failCount;
    }   
}
```

Please make sure to create model pojo class with similar names specified in query for mongo mapping to work.

**Mongo Shell Equivalent:**

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "date": {
                "$gte": {
                    "$date": "2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"
                },
                "$lte": {
                    "$date": "2019-12-31T13:43:17.106Z"
                },
                "$exists": true
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "month": {
                    "$month": "$date"
                }
            },
            "passCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [{
                        "$eq": ["$status", "Pass"]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            "failCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [{
                        "$eq": ["$status", "Fail"]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```